# How do we measure the gluon scattering?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, s-matrix-theory, gluons

In QFT, we often calculate the 'Feynman amplitude' for gluon scattering. As we know, Gluon is gauge boson mediating the strong force between quarks. By color confinement, Quarks are never seen in our energy level, they are literally confined in mesons and baryons like $\pi$ or $n,p$. In other words, we cannot see the interaction of gluons directly.

So I wonder what the 'Feynman amplitude' for gluon scattering means for and used in which situation. In case of $gg \rightarrow gg$, can we detect the differential cross section for this or for  $gg\rightarrow q \bar q$?

Comment: Your QFT text should review [jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)) of colorless hadrons the colored primary quarks and [gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) dress themselves to.

Comment: maybe this review of experiments  will help understand the complexity https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01819-3 . from the abstract "measurements show an intriguing sensitivity to gluons, the carriers of the strong interaction."